# Checking in Renamed SLN to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, tfsbuild

I renamed the solution file through TFS and tried checking the code in.  I keep getting this error.  My best guess is that the build does not recognize that the name of the solution changed, and keeps looking for the old name.

Exception Message: The file (oldName).sln could not be found. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

How do I get the build to accept the new sln file?  Any assistance in the resolution of this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the build definition, go to the process tab, and in the solutions to build property update the name of your solution.