# Remove solution from TFS - FileNotFound Exception on build

Tags: c#, tfs, source-control-explorer

i am trying to remove solution in TFS via source control explorer. When I right-click the solution, select Delete and check-in, the build crashes with message:

> Exception Message: The project file 'C:\Path\On\Server\solution.sln' was not found. (type FileNotFoundException)
>
> Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
>      at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>      at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

There was also problem with removing other files from source control (build crashed with FileNotFound exception), but that was solved by having dummy file on local machine when the build was running. Unfortunately this solution does not work for this problem.

The solution.sln is leftover after move operation (i had to create copy and keep the original solution - the one i want to remove - in its position, otherwise it would crash the build with FileNotFound Exception mentioned above)

Does anyone had similar issue and know how to remove the solution from source control (without destroy command if possible)?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**EDIT:**

Added solution to this issue. If you think it's redundant question (it's basically the same issue as the one mentioned in [Checking in Renamed SLN to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272562/checking-in-renamed-sln-to-tfs?rq=1)) then i can remove it completely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution mentioned in [Checking in Renamed SLN to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272562/checking-in-renamed-sln-to-tfs?rq=1) worked. It was **necesarry to remove old solution.sln from build definition**. (Edit Build Definition\Process tab\Items to build - remove path to solution)